# Laravel Routes Not Working

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I worked with Laravel 4 before and never had any problems.
I think I don't do anything wrong, but please help me.

I have a route:

```
Route::get('redirect', 'TestController@newRedirect');
```

And the controller:

```
<?php

class TestController extends \BaseController {

    public function newRedirect()
    {
        echo "Yes!";
    }

}
```

But I get:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What's the URL you're visiting? Exactly. Can remove the prepended file structure if you like

Comment: http://localhost:8000/redirect     - What do you mean with: "Can remove the prepended file structure if you like"

Comment: Is that route defintion in the routes.php file? Is your controller autoloaded correctly? Have you tried running `php artisan routes` to see if the route is listed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it on some other port with php artisan serve --port=8001

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Route::get('/redirect', 'TestController@newRedirect');
```

or, even better, named route

```
Route::get('/redirect', array('as' => 'redirect', 'uses' => 'TestController@newRedirect'));
```

Comment: @RobinKuiper What if you do `php composer dump-autoload` and change your Newredirect function by `return echo "Yes!";`?

Comment: I think you mean "php ARTISAN dump-autoload" ? Tried that already thought, just gives "Generating optimized class loader". Tried the return to, no difference.